# Dynamic SQL, parameterized Query

Tags: sql-server, parameter-passing, dynamic-sql, alwayson

I've written a query which pulls SQL AlwaysON health information. The only thing left to do is add a where clause in the end to filter the AvailabilityGroupName and DatabaseName. It works when I put in the query: 'select * from results where AvailabilityGroupName = 'LAB-VIP-USADB' AND DatabaseName = 'CPS''. However when I store the query in a nvarchar variable @sql in the beginning and later on execute the query stored in the variable, I received error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'". The reason why I want to paramerterized the query is that one availability group could contain multiple databases. The paramterized input will come from PRTG so that it queries the Availability group for that specific database.

```html
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql='SELECT * FROM Results WHERE AvailabilityGroupName = ''LAB-VIP-USADB'' AND DatabaseName = ''CPS'''
--select @sql
;
WITH basicaginfo AS(
SELECT 
      
       ag.name AS AvailabilityGroupName,
       cs.replica_server_name AS NodeName,
       rs.role_desc,
       rs.synchronization_health_desc,
       DB_NAME(drs.database_id) AS DatabaseName
       


FROM 
       sys.availability_groups ag
                    JOIN
       sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_states cs on ag.group_id = cs.group_id
                    JOIN
       sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states rs ON (ag.group_id=rs.group_id AND cs.replica_id = rs.replica_id)
                    JOIN
       sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states drs ON (ag.group_id=drs.group_id AND cs.replica_id = drs.replica_id)
             

     ),

   
       AG_Stats AS 
                    (
                    SELECT AR.replica_server_name,
                              HARS.role_desc, 
                              Db_name(DRS.database_id) [DBName], 
                              DRS.last_commit_time
                    FROM   sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states DRS 
                    INNER JOIN sys.availability_replicas AR ON DRS.replica_id = AR.replica_id 
                    INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states HARS ON AR.group_id = HARS.group_id 
                           AND AR.replica_id = HARS.replica_id 
                    ),
       Pri_CommitTime AS 
                    (
                    SELECT replica_server_name
                                 , DBName
                                 , last_commit_time
                    FROM   AG_Stats
                    WHERE  role_desc = 'PRIMARY'
                    ),
       Sec_CommitTime AS 
                    (
                    SELECT replica_server_name
                                 , DBName
                                 , last_commit_time
                    FROM   AG_Stats
                    WHERE  role_desc = 'SECONDARY'
                    ),
  Results AS
     (
     SELECT 
      AvailabilityGroupName, 
      DatabaseName, 
      [LAB-SCB-SQL01],
      [LAB-SCB-SQL02], 
      [LAB-LAS-SQL01], 
      [LAB-LAS-SQL02], 
      [Max_Sync_Lag_Secs]
     FROM(
       SELECT 
        bb.AvailabilityGroupName, 
        bb.DatabaseName,
        bb.NodeName,
        bb.synchronization_health_desc,
        MAX( DATEDIFF(ss,s.last_commit_time,p.last_commit_time)) OVER ( PARTITION BY NULL ) AS [Max_Sync_Lag_Secs]
   
       FROM 
        basicaginfo bb
         LEFT JOIN
        Pri_CommitTime p ON p.DBName=bb.DatabaseName 
         LEFT JOIN 
        Sec_CommitTime s ON bb.NodeName = s.replica_server_name
      ) AS Data
     PIVOT(

       MAX( synchronization_health_desc ) FOR [NodeName] IN( [LAB-SCB-SQL01], [LAB-SCB-SQL02], [LAB-LAS-SQL01], [LAB-LAS-SQL02] )
       ) AS PivotedData
     )
EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it, cte tables are accessible only to the next SQL command.

When you execute the command EXEC(@sql) internally the SQL excutes more than one command.

Try to move all code to a variable.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql=N'WITH basicaginfo AS(
SELECT 

       ag.name AS AvailabilityGroupName,
       cs.replica_server_name AS NodeName,
       rs.role_desc,
       rs.synchronization_health_desc,
       DB_NAME(drs.database_id) AS DatabaseName



FROM 
       sys.availability_groups ag
                    JOIN
       sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_states cs on ag.group_id = cs.group_id
                    JOIN
       sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states rs ON (ag.group_id=rs.group_id AND cs.replica_id = rs.replica_id)
                    JOIN
       sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states drs ON (ag.group_id=drs.group_id AND cs.replica_id = drs.replica_id)


                    ),


       AG_Stats AS 
                    (
                    SELECT AR.replica_server_name,
                              HARS.role_desc, 
                              Db_name(DRS.database_id) [DBName], 
                              DRS.last_commit_time
                    FROM   sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states DRS 
                    INNER JOIN sys.availability_replicas AR ON DRS.replica_id = AR.replica_id 
                    INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states HARS ON AR.group_id = HARS.group_id 
                           AND AR.replica_id = HARS.replica_id 
                    ),
       Pri_CommitTime AS 
                    (
                    SELECT replica_server_name
                                 , DBName
                                 , last_commit_time
                    FROM   AG_Stats
                    WHERE  role_desc = ''PRIMARY''
                    ),
       Sec_CommitTime AS 
                    (
                    SELECT replica_server_name
                                 , DBName
                                 , last_commit_time
                    FROM   AG_Stats
                    WHERE  role_desc = ''SECONDARY''
                    ),
        Results AS
                    (
                    SELECT 
                        AvailabilityGroupName, 
                        DatabaseName, 
                        [LAB-SCB-SQL01],
                        [LAB-SCB-SQL02], 
                        [LAB-LAS-SQL01], 
                        [LAB-LAS-SQL02], 
                        [Max_Sync_Lag_Secs]
                    FROM(
                            SELECT 
                                bb.AvailabilityGroupName, 
                                bb.DatabaseName,
                                bb.NodeName,
                                bb.synchronization_health_desc,
                                MAX( DATEDIFF(ss,s.last_commit_time,p.last_commit_time)) OVER ( PARTITION BY NULL ) AS [Max_Sync_Lag_Secs]

                            FROM 
                                basicaginfo bb
                                    LEFT JOIN
                                Pri_CommitTime p ON p.DBName=bb.DatabaseName 
                                    LEFT JOIN 
                                Sec_CommitTime s ON bb.NodeName = s.replica_server_name
                        ) AS Data
                    PIVOT(

                            MAX( synchronization_health_desc ) FOR [NodeName] IN( [LAB-SCB-SQL01], [LAB-SCB-SQL02], [LAB-LAS-SQL01], [LAB-LAS-SQL02] )
                         ) AS PivotedData
                    )
                    SELECT * FROM Results WHERE AvailabilityGroupName = ''LAB-VIP-USADB'' AND DatabaseName = ''CPS'''
EXEC(@sql)
```

I tryed run this command in my environment and I got the error bellow because I do not have on it the tables.

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.availability_groups'.
```